# How to represent a subgraph of a directed graph as a LayeredGraph with EdgeWeights

Tags: graphs-and-networks, formatting

The following `code` generates:

[image]

The first element is a layered graph of the original system `sam`. The second element is a list of all the pathways from `L` to `G`. The third element is a directed graph in which the extracted pathways are highlighted. The fourth element is this highlighted subgraph. I like to achieve the following:

1. In the first element `LayeredGraph`, edge weights should be placed on each edge with properly distanced edge lengths. Currently, the edge between `A` and `L` does not appear properly.
2. The fourth element should be formatted like the first layered graph. Currently, vertex names inside circles and edge weights are all missing.

Here is what I have developed:

```
ClearAll[vnames, sam];
vnames = {"A", "X", "Q", "L", "K", "H", "G", "CA", "YTAX", "STAX", "TAR", "ROW"};
sam = {{0, PX QX, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, PD QD, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, -TE, exr pwe QE}, {PQ QINT, 0, 0, 0, 0, PQ QH, PQ QG, 
  PQ QINV, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {PL QL, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0}, {PK QK, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, PL QL, 
  PK QK, 0, TR[H, g], 0, 0, 0, 0, exr TR[H, rw]}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, YTAX, STAX, TAR, exr TR[g, rw]}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  s YH (1 - t[H]), SAV[g], 0, 0, 0, 0, exr SAV[rw]}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  YH t[H], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, STAX, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0}, {0, 0, TM, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, exr pwm QM, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}};
    
    (*from @KGLR*)
    edgeW = Module[{g = #, 
         e = DirectedEdge @@@ Partition[#, 2, 1] & /@ 
           FindPath[##, \[Infinity], All]}, 
        Transpose[{e, PropertyValue[{g, #}, EdgeWeight] & /@ # & /@ e}]] &;
    subGraphF = Module[
        {el = edgeW[##][[All, 1]]},
        Graph[DeleteDuplicates[Flatten@el], 
         VertexCapacity -> {v_ :> PropertyValue[{#, v}, VertexCapacity]}, 
         EdgeWeight -> {e_ :> PropertyValue[{#, e}, EdgeWeight]}]] &;
    
    wag = WeightedAdjacencyGraph[vnames, 
       Transpose@sam /. {0 -> \[Infinity]}, VertexLabels -> "Name", 
       EdgeLabels -> "EdgeWeight", ImageSize -> 300];
    
    source = "L";
    sink = "G";
    {
     LayeredGraphPlot[{"A" -> "Q", "A" -> "L", "A" -> "K", "X" -> "A", 
       "Q" -> "X", "Q" -> "STAX", "Q" -> "TAR", "Q" -> "ROW", "L" -> "H", 
       "K" -> "H", "H" -> "Q", "H" -> "CA", "H" -> "YTAX", "G" -> "Q", 
       "G" -> "H", "G" -> "CA", "CA" -> "Q", "YTAX" -> "G", "STAX" -> "G",
        "TAR" -> "X", "TAR" -> "G", "ROW" -> "X", "ROW" -> "H", 
       "ROW" -> "G", "ROW" -> "CA"}, Left, VertexLabeling -> True, 
      EdgeRenderingFunction -> ({Brown, Arrow[#1, 0.4]} &), 
      VertexRenderingFunction -> ({LightGray, EdgeForm[Black], 
          Disk[#, .3], Black, Text[#2, #1]} &), ImageSize -> 400],
     TableForm[edgeW[wag, source, sink]],     
      HighlightGraph[wag, subGraphF[wag, source, sink], 
      GraphHighlight -> {source, sink}, ImageSize -> 400, 
      EdgeLabels -> "EdgeWeight"],
     subGraphF[wag, source, 
      sink]     (* all paths from source to sink: a subgraph *)
     }
```

Comment: looks like you are using version 11.*?

Comment: @kglr: Yes indeed, I use version 11.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.**

```
options = {EdgeLabels -> Placed["EdgeWeight", 11/20], 
  ImageSize -> 600, VertexSize -> Large, 
  VertexStyle -> Directive[LightGray, EdgeForm[Black]], 
  VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], EdgeStyle -> Brown, 
  VertexShapeFunction -> (Disk[#, Offset[16]] &), 
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", AspectRatio -> 3/4}; 

Graph[wag, GraphLayout -> {"LayeredDigraphEmbedding", "Orientation" -> Left}, options]
```

[image]

**Note:** In versions 12.+, you can also use `LayeredGraphPlot[wag, Left, options]` to get a `Graphics` object with the same picture.

**2.**

```
Graph[subGraphF[wag, source, sink], options]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. It works perfectly.

Comment: @TugrulTemel, my pleasure. Thank you for accepting.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the new edition, which is much more compact relative to the previous version.

Comment: Can you color "source" and "sink" with Red, for example, in order to clearly illustrate the start and target vertices?

Comment: @TugrulTemel, try `SetProperty[Graph[subGraphF[wag, source, sink], options], 
 VertexStyle -> {(source | sink) -> Red}]`.